# Is it possible to have properties in the root AppState alongside child states?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

Is it possible for the root AppState to contain normal properties aside from child states?
I need a place in the store that can be accessed globally in the application
and when using `ActionReducerMap`as below you need to provide reducer functions for each child state you have in the app but it doesn't seem like I can add normal properties to the AppState itself

```
export interface AppState {
router: RouterReducerState;
[homeFeatureKey]: HomeState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
router: routerReducer,
[homeFeatureKey]: homeReducer
};
```